# merge two rows into one adding unique data

Tags: mysql

I have two rows for every order in a MYSQL database, they both have all the same information aside from:

**pickup-location-id**

I was wondering if there is a way to merge the rows into one while concatenating the

**pickup-location-id** for EX row1

**pickup-location-id2** for EX row2

Into ***ONE ROW*** with the order-id used for both.

This is the closest I got....

```
SELECT *
    FROM `t_order-transportation`
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `pickup-location` AS `pickup-location-2`,
                `order-id`
               FROM `t_order-transportation`
               GROUP  BY `pickup-location`
               HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
           ON `t_order-transportation`.`order-id` = dup.`order-id`
```

this is doing almost what I want, but it seems to be displaying 4 rows, 2 for the originals, and 2 for the new rows with the concationation both ways.

[Sample of select return || RED IS ORIGINAL ROWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRXT.png)

MYSQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b441/1

Comment: please elaborate it more and provide sql fiddle

Comment: added fiddle although fiddle doesn't return 4 rows, only showing 2. Also tried to explain better.

Comment: Do you need pickup-locations in sepparated fields or can be concatenated in only one field? If don't matter, you can use GROUP_CONCAT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I need the 2nd pickup location in a new field, which I would use the returned result to map to a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a simple Inner Join

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM `t_order-transportation` as a
INNER JOIN `t_order-transportation` as b 
              on ( a.`order-id` = b.`order-id` 
                 and a.`pickup-datetime` < b.`pickup-datetime`)
```

for the location  you can

```
SELECT a.*, b.`pickup-location`
FROM `t_order-transportation` as a
INNER JOIN `t_order-transportation` as b 
              on (a.`order-id` = b.`order-id`
               and a.`pickup-datetime` < b.`pickup-datetime`)
```

Comment: This seems to be a better structure, although this isn't exactly performing the full action I am looking for. Just want to merge the rows together while adding the unique value of the 2nd row.

Comment: I have update tyhe answer adding only pickup-location for second table  .. i hope this is what you are looking for .. anyway let me know ..

Comment: This is producing the same result I have now, with a simpler query, it is returning 4 rows for every order-id is the only problem now.

Comment: Adding  WHERE a.`pickup-location` != b.`pickup-location` to the clause seems to bring it down to 2 rows, now just need to make it 1 row per order-id

Comment: I have update the answer adding a.pickup-datetime <a.pickup-datetime this should  return two rows one for each order